# Now that `/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png` has changed, where is the solid purple background screen file stored?

Tags: unity, 15.04, lightdm, login-screen, desktop-background

Now that `/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png` has changed, where is the solid purple background screen file stored?

`/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png` is the default background, however, before `/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png` loads, a purple background is displayed for a second or two.

Where is the solid background screen stored now that `/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png` has been changed?

Comment: Is it it possible it's just a colour? I don't have Unity in 15.04 on hand to check, but GNOME lets you set a colour as the background IIRC, so it's possible Unity does too.

Comment: I would like to change it to black

Comment: I believe the color is `#2C001E` , read by: `gsettings get com.canonical.unity-greeter background-color` and set to black by: `gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background-color '#000000'` Is that the color you are referring to? *Edit*: nope, that's not it, changed it to green but it didn't show up on startup... must be somewhere in the keys though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes, black is #000000. I just found this setting in dconf.

Comment: @JacobVlijm dconf doesn't work either but I figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no file, however there is a way to change the color.

Run the following commands:

```
echo "[com.canonical.unity-greeter]" | sudo tee /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override
echo "draw-user-backgrounds=true" | sudo tee -a /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override
echo "background-color='#000000'" | sudo tee -a /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Of course, this changes the screen to black.

More setting options such as setting the background to a static image can be found at the source link below.

[source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)