# Set lightdm/login to default

Tags: 14.04, unity, login, lightdm, desktop-background

I tried setting the login screen background to my wallpaper, and this works for locking once I'm signed in, but when I boot up I just get a solid color purple screen, and it totally glitches when I sign in, but eventually goes to the desktop. How can I either fix this (preferably setting it statically to my desktop wallpaper), or at the very least reset it to default? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to edit the following file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override
```

Then copy and paste this into the file and replace `/foo/wallpaper.png` with the actual path to the actual file you would like to use for wallpaper (remember to put it in ' marks or this won't work!):

```
[com.canonical.unity-greeter]
draw-user-backgrounds=false
background='/foo/wallpaper.png'
```

alternatively, to set it to default, use this instead:

```
[com.canonical.unity-greeter]
draw-user-backgrounds=true
background='/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

When you are finished, run the following command to apply the changes:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

[source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)

Comment: Tried this exactly, no dice. Still got a solid dark purple background, and a weird spazzy glitch before loading the desktop. Functional... but ugly and annoying.

Comment: @cosmoflop12  You know, the dark purple color can be set also  by editing this same file. You can change it to black like in this answer to my own question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/673104/now-that-usr-share-backgrounds-warty-final-ubuntu-png-has-changed-where-is-t/673888#673888

Comment: @cosmoflop12 Also, if the file is a jpg image, you may have trouble. I think I remember reading something about how the file needs to be a png.

Comment: It's a png. And honestly the color doesn't bug me that much... It's just the glitching out. Everything goes whack towards the top of the screen for a significant amount of time (longer than it'd usually take to log in) before going to my desktop.

Comment: you can check your xorg log in systemlog or dmesg for more info.

Comment: Ran dmesg, got a long thing that seemed to have quite a few errors included. Would it help if I posted that here?

Comment: Sorry if I'm kinda having trouble, it's late and I'm kinda still a beginner with this stuff.

Comment: probably too big to post. I'll try to find the right stuff to flag and will post a command that will only print the relevant stuff.

Comment: @cosmoflop12 this might be better `dmesg | grep -iC 3 "error"`

Comment: Ok still pretty long. I'm gonna put this in a google drive document and put a link.

Comment: Here it is: https://goo.gl/xJIo0h

Comment: i didn't see much about video. maybe check xorg  logs in the systemlog app. Also, there are settings in ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager). You can mess with the opengl settings there and sometimes that helps.

Comment: @cosmoflop12 If it is solid purple, see my answer here on how to change that to black. http://askubuntu.com/questions/673104/now-that-usr-share-backgrounds-warty-final-ubuntu-png-has-changed-where-is-t

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue. Set the login screen to an image with permissions for only one user. Made it readable across all and now it works!