# /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf file and /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf missing

Tags: unity, xorg, login, lightdm, login-screen

In my Ubuntu 14.04 `/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf`  and `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` files are missing. **Only** `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` file is there in `/etc/lightdm/` directory.

And login screen is not smooth either. Sometimes when typing the password, it does not appearing. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the lightdm configuration files now reside in /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/ - I don't think your non-smoothness issue is related to that

Comment: As of 14.04 you have to create whatever files and folders you need. That's the short answer. There's sample conf files somewhere in /usr, but i can't recall of the top of my head which exact path

Comment: I think I had this issue but can't remember exactly what needs to be done to fix it. It is possibly a missing font or missing theme or could just be misconfigured.

Answer (score 3):

Those files no longer exist and are depreciated. Configuration is now done through individual files located in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`.

If you want do some configuration, maybe [see this answer as an example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673877/set-lightdm-login-to-default).

Alternatively, [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/500040/167115) on how to set default manager now that lightdm.conf does not exist.